# IE8 caching gone to new heights

Tags: internet-explorer, caching, internet-explorer-8

So I was happily developing my fancy new website (with jQuery 1.11.1) and decided to make sure it at least *functions* in IE8, on Windows XP no less.

I fixed one Javascript bug and now I've run into the worst situation of caching I've seen.

Before I go ahead and add a "version" tag to my HTML script tag, I tried clearing the cache from Dev Tools, clearing everything in the Internet Options "browsing history", even so far as to remove every trace of anything from the entire Temporary Internet Files directory (and Content.IE5 which still had files littered throughout).

Even with seemingly *no cached files at all*, the old buggy version of my Javascript file is still running when I load up the website from a fresh instance of IE8.

Is there a ghost script haunting my machine?

Comment: Adding a random GET parameter fixed the issue by the way, but any change to the scripts requires this to change of course :(

Comment: The query-string approach is the typical *cache-busting* method, however what you're describing as the original scenario sounds pretty incredible. If you deleted all cache, including the flat files, the only way a browser could get anything would be from the server. Are you possible your server wasn't responding with an older file?

Comment: @JonathanSampson not unless it was responding differently to IE than to the Chrome browser I typically use? Simply doing a refresh works just fine in Chrome.